# How to read and parse gruntfile programatically so I can modify it and save again?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am creating a complex Yeoman Generator and I need to read an existing gruntfile and modify it.

Any javascript way of parsing a gruntfile is enought.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to modify? The config object? Or add custom functionality on a modular basis?

Comment: I need to include more paths to existing browserify, sass and uglify tasks

Comment: How much control do you have over the overall scaffolding of the project?

Answer (score 2):

imo i dont think you can achieve that by parsing js files and generating a new gruntfile.

instead of doing that you can try creating template files ex. `.jade` (or another template engine) so , you can produce the final gruntfile, you can look into grunt configuration object [grunt.config](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config) and eventually read information, interpolate data into your template(s) and produce the final `gruntfile.js`.

Comment: So you are saying I should use `grunt.config` to read/write an existing grunt config, but it is only possible to use grunt.config inside gruntfile.js so I should store it in a json file that I can easily read.

Comment: you can `require` it as module and "browse" the object properties and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modular approach to grunt that you can use without having to modify `gruntfile.js` every time you add new tasks, plugin or custom.

1. Add `load-grunt-tasks` [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-grunt-tasks) as a dev dependency: `npm install load-grunt-tasks --save-dev`.  This plugin allows you to load all your grunt dependencies using one line of code.
2. Specify a folder in your project to hold all your modular configuration files.  This example uses the path `grunt/configs/`.  Each json file's name should match the it's property name in the grunt config.  For example, the config for `grunt-copy-config` should be `grunt/configs/copy.json`
3. Copy the gruntfile.js I've posted as a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/theaccordance/4a4aecad222f4008abf8a1bd7867d049) (stack overflow wasn't formatting the code properly).  This gruntfile will automatically load your plugins and compile a config object using the project's `package.json` file and every .json file found in `grunt/configs/`.  The gruntfile also loads any custom tasks I've saved into `grunt/tasks/`

As an alternate option - you can host your modular config objects in JavaScript files instead of json files (that's what I do).  This provides me with the capability to dynamically compile my config objects if I need to.  If that's something that interests you, I can share that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the tips, great ideas, with your guidance I came up using a json file for each configuration:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        browserify: grunt.file.readJSON('browserify.json'),
        uglify: grunt.file.readJSON('uglify.json'),
        sass: grunt.file.readJSON('sass.json'),
        cssmin: grunt.file.readJSON('cssmin.json'),
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify', 'sass']);
    grunt.registerTask('production', ['browserify', 'sass', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);

};
```

Now I can easily modify the configuration